# SVG circle with multiple origin for stroke animation

Tags: css, svg

I have a simple donut graph with fill-in animation. The problem is that I get two separate paths. (Es. 10% bar gives me 0-10% and then space and then another 10%.

I have tried playing around with the different variables but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, any help? I have used this: https://codepen.io/matttherat/pen/EeMaEw?editors=1100

Here's a screen:

[image: a busy cat]

```css
.svg-item {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
  max-width: 120px;
  animation: donutfade 1s;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.data-des {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

@keyframes donutfade {
  /* this applies to the whole svg item wrapper */
  0% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.donut-ring-ext {
  stroke: #50b180;
}

.donut-segment {
  transform-origin: center;
}

.donut-segment-2 {
  stroke: #a8df8a;
  animation: donut1 1s;
}

.donut-segment-3 {
  stroke: #a8df8a;
  animation: donut2 1s;
}

.donut-segment-4 {
  stroke: #a8df8a;
  animation: donut3 1s;
}

.donut-percent {
  color: #3c8560;
  animation: donutfadelong 1s;
}

@keyframes donutfadelong {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes donut1 {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 10 90;
  }
}

@keyframes donut2 {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0, 100;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 20, 80;
  }
}

@keyframes donut3 {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0, 100;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 50, 50;
  }
}

.donut-label {
  font-size: 0.28em;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  fill: #000;
  transform: translateY(0.25em);
}

.donut-percent {
  font-size: 0.5em;
  line-height: 1;
  transform: translateY(0.5em);
  font-weight: 100;
}

.donut-data {
  font-size: 0.12em;
  line-height: 1;
  transform: translateY(0.5em);
  text-align: center;
  text-anchor: middle;
  color: #666;
  fill: #666;
  animation: donutfadelong 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-item">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 40 40" class="donut">
                                <circle
                                    class="donut-hole"
                                    cx="20"
                                    cy="20"
                                    r="15.91549430918954"
                                    fill="#fff"
                                ></circle>
                                <circle
                                    class="donut-ring-ext"
                                    cx="20"
                                    cy="20"
                                    r="19"
                                    fill="transparent"
                                    stroke-width="2"
                                ></circle>
                                <circle
                                    class="donut-segment donut-segment-2"
                                    cx="20"
                                    cy="20"
                                    r="22"
                                    fill="transparent"
                                    stroke-width="2"
                                    stroke-dasharray="10 90"
                                    stroke-dashoffset="-5"
                                ></circle>
                                <g class="donut-text donut-text-1">
                                    <text y="50%" transform="translate(0, 2)">
                                        <tspan
                                            x="50%"
                                            text-anchor="middle"
                                            class="donut-percent"
                                        >
                                            10%
                                        </tspan>
                                    </text>
                                </g>
                                <span class="data-des">Amet dolorem sit</span>
                            </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue lies with your `stroke-dasharray`: it is a repeating pattern that has a dash of 10px long, and then a space of 90px long, and then the pattern repeats. However, the circumference of your path is not 100px. You will need to use JS to compute the exact numbers, since you need to [calculate the total length of the path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/getTotalLength). E.g. if your total circumference is 450px long, then your stroke dasharray should be set to `45 395`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to animate the stroke-dashoffset attribute. At the beginning stroke-dasharay = the path's total length (calculated with `.getTotalLength()`). Since you are using only one value the dashes and the gaps are of equal length.

```
stroke-dasharray="137.35"
```

Also the `stroke-dashoffset="137.35"`. This means that you don't see the dash. In this moment your stroke is the gap.

Next you are animating the `stroke-dashoffset`. If you want to see 10% of the dash yoi need to animate the `stroke-dashoffset` from 100% to 90% i.e

```
 100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 123.6;
  }
```

I hope it helps.

```css
.svg-item {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 16px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.data-des {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.donut-ring-ext {
  stroke: #50b180;
}

.donut-segment {
  transform-origin: center;
}

.donut-segment-2 {
  stroke: #a8df8a;
  animation: donut1 1s forwards;
}

.donut-segment-3 {
  stroke: #a8df8a;
  animation: donut2 1s;
}

.donut-segment-4 {
  stroke: #a8df8a;
  animation: donut3 1s;
}

.donut-percent {
  color: #3c8560;
  animation: donutfadelong 1s;
}



@keyframes donut1 {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 123.6;
  }
}


.donut-label {
  font-size: 0.28em;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  fill: #000;
  transform: translateY(0.25em);
}

.donut-percent {
  font-size: 0.5em;
  line-height: 1;
  transform: translateY(0.5em);
  font-weight: 100;
}

.donut-data {
  font-size: 0.12em;
  line-height: 1;
  transform: translateY(0.5em);
  text-align: center;
  text-anchor: middle;
  color: #666;
  fill: #666;
  animation: donutfadelong 1s;
}

svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<div class="svg-item">
  <svg viewBox="-30 -10 100 100" class="donut">
  <g transform="rotate(-90 20 20)">
                                <circle
                                    class="donut-hole"
                                    cx="20"
                                    cy="20"
                                    r="15.91549430918954"
                                    fill="#f00"
                                ></circle>
                                <circle
                                    class="donut-ring-ext"
                                    cx="20"
                                    cy="20"
                                    r="19"
                                    fill="transparent"
                                    stroke-width="2"
                                ></circle>
                                <circle 
                                    class="donut-segment donut-segment-2"
                                    cx="20"
                                    cy="20"
                                    r="22"
                                    fill="transparent"
                                    stroke-width="2"
                                    stroke-dasharray="137.35"
                                    stroke-dashoffset="137.35"
                                ></circle></g>
                                <g class="donut-text donut-text-1">
                                    <text y="50%" transform="translate(0, 2)">
                                        <tspan
                                            x="50%"
                                            text-anchor="middle"
                                            class="donut-percent"
                                        >
                                            10%
                                        </tspan>
                                    </text>
                                </g>
                                <span class="data-des">Amet dolorem sit</span>
                            </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I have managed to fix the double but how can I get the stroke to start from a specific point (top of the circle) rather than the side?
Also, where does 137.35 come from?

Comment: I've updated my example. I'm wrapping the circles in a ` <g transform="rotate(-90 20 20)">`  this is rotating the hole group -90 degs around the center 20,20. Please take a look.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Just a question, who do you apply .getTotalLength() to? To which element? Thanks!

Comment: In this case you need to know the length of the circle `.donut-segment.donut-segment-2` So in javascript you can do `let theCircle = document.querySelector(".donut-segment.donut-segment-2"); console.log(theCircle.getTotalLength())`. This will give you 137.35. Please take a look at [How SVG Line Animation Works](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/)